# JQuery sortable iterate over elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have this website using JQuerys sortable function which makes it possible for me to drag items on a list. Every item on the list has a button that corresponds to that item and is connected to an image on the site. I need that image `z-index` to be changed when the user has dragged an item to another place than where it is. Right now I am just changing the `alt` attribut to make it easier for myself, but my code looks like this:

```
var data = $(this).sortable("serialize");
var change_zindex = 1;
var drag_id_tmp = $(ui.item).attr("id");
var drag_id = drag_id_tmp.split("-")[1];

document.getElementsByClassName('item' + drag_id)[0].setAttribute("alt", change_zindex);
```

The code knows what item is dragged, the problem is that the `alt` attribute is just set equal to `1` right now, and it is supposed to be set to the value corresponding to the place the user dragged the item to. Does anybody know how that's possible? Thanks in advance. Please tell me if you want me to provide you with more code.

EDIT:

works in my database, like this:

```
/* Insert the parameter values */
        $i = 0;

        foreach ($_POST['item'] as $value) {

            /* Register a prepared statement */
            if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('UPDATE house_room1 SET z = ? WHERE ref_id = ?')) {

                /* Bind parametres */
                $stmt->bind_param('ii', $i, $value);

                /* Execute the query */
                $stmt->execute();

                /* Close statement */
                $stmt->close();

            } else {
                /* Something went wrong */
                echo 'Something went terribly wrong' . $mysqli->error;
            }
            $i++;
        }
```

It's in a array using serialize I believe, also added the serialize to the AJAX code

Current status:

AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#sortable").sortable({
        axis: "y",
        stop: function (event, ui) {

            var data = $(this).sortable("serialize");

             var change_zindex = 1;
             var drag_id_tmp = $(ui.item).attr("id");
             var drag_id = drag_id_tmp.split("-")[1];
             document.getElementsByClassName('item' + drag_id)[0].setAttribute("alt", item);

             $('ul li').each(function(index, item){
                 $(item).children('span').attr('alt', drag_id + 1)
             });

            $.ajax({
                data: data,
                type: "POST",
                url: "database/update_settings_sort.php"
            });
        }
    });
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
});
```

The HTML I'm working with:
For the image with the z-index:

```
echo '<img src="' . $src . $rotation .'.png" class="item' . $item_number . '" 
rel="'.$rotation.'" alt="'.$z.'"style="position:absolute; left:' . $x . 'px; top:' . $y . 
'px; z-index:'. $z . ';">'; if ($x != 0) { echo'</a>'; }
```

html for the actual list:

```
echo '<li id="item-' . $arr['number'] . '" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>' . $arr['name'] . ' 
<img class="rotate" id="img_'.$arr['number'].'" src="images/house/other/settings.jpg" onclick="rotateObject(this,\''. $arr['src']. '\')">';
```

Comment: What do you mean "it is supposed to be set to the value corresponding to the place the user dragged the item to."  Does that mean if you have 10 elements and you drag the 9th element to the 2nd spot, the value should now be 2?  If that's the case, do you need to now change the value of all the spots in between the old #2-#8 to now be #3-#9?  Create a fiddle or plunkr.

Comment: @VtoCorleone thats correct, I does exactly this in my database but I can't figure out to do it in JS. I can post my database code, it just goes through an array using serialize.

Answer (score 5):

You can hook in to the stop even when the item is dropped and then renumber all of the "alt" tags to whatever value you want.  In the example below, I have the list items listed as 1-7.  Once an item is dropped, it iterates over the list items and renumbers them.

```
$( "#sortable" ).sortable({

     // Hook into stop event of sortable
     stop: function( event, ui ) {

         // Iterate over all of the list items
         $('ul li').each(function(index, item){

              // Set each items "alt" attribute to it's corresponding spot in the list.
              // Added +1 so that it uses numbers 1-7 instead of 0-6
              $(item).children('span').attr('alt', index + 1)   
         });
     }
});
```

[Here's a fiddle for it.](http://jsfiddle.net/VtoCorleone/5y4A5/)

Comment: Thank you very much for this great example! but is it me, or is the alt value always equal to `2` even though the draggable elements are dragged to other positions? And would I be able to implement this with my own example? Thanks again

Comment: Nope.  They are in order.  Add this code 
    debugger;
    $('ul li').children('span');
after the .each function and open dev tools/firebug when you do the sorting.  It will break after you do the sort and you can see all of the values of the 'alt' tags.  They're all in order.  If this worked, would you mind marking it correct please.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm not quite sure where to add the span in my example compared to yours, could you please take a look at the code above? I added it to the question, thanks a lot